# Conceptual questions about permutation vs combination

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three students are chosen at random. Find the probability that exactly 1 is studying music and exactly 2 are boys. The following is their

[image]

Here's what I'm doing:
$$ P(BM) \times P(BM') \times P(GM') + P(GM) \times P(BM') \times P(BM')$$
$$ = \frac{40}{160} \times \frac{56}{159} \times \frac{52}{158} + \frac{12}{160} \times \frac{56}{159} \times \frac{55}{158} $$

I have two questions:

1. This is a selection, so order chosen is not important. Why does the answer key multiply the first scenario by $3!$ and the second scenario by $3!/2!$?
2. Why are we multiplying the second scenario by $3!/2!$? Aren't the boys distinct?

Comment: You can treat order as important or not important however you like... but in doing so you need both your numerator *and* your denominator to match in whether or not you treated order as important.  If you want to treat order as not important, your denominator should have been $\binom{160}{3}$, not $160\cdot 159\cdot 158$, hence the book's multiplication by $3!$.

Comment: As for why in the one scenario it was $3!$ while in the other it was $3!/2!$... that is because $BM$ is not able to be confused with $BM'$ nor with $GM'$.  All three of the specific person-types we were looking for were unique in the first scenario.  In the second scenario, we are looking for two persons of the type $BM'$ and these two can be confused with one another.